# Jquery - click event added inside another click prevents the original click

Tags: jquery

In a login box, I have added a button called 'Reset Password'. When that button is clicked I show few more fields in the same form and button shows 'Cancel'. But when 'Cancel' is clicked and added fields go away the original button stops working for consecutive clicks.

```
<div class="show_hide_login_box margin10-right">
    <dl>    <dt>Username:</dt>

        <dd>
            <input type="text" class="input" value="admin@xento.com" name="company_user[username]" readonly="true"><span style="display:none;">@xento</span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl id="passward_link" style="display: block;"> <dt>Password:</dt>

        <dd>
            <input type="text" class="input" value="admin@xento.com" name="company_user[username]" readonly="true"><span style="display:none;">@xento</span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <div id="password_fields" style="display: none;">
        <dl>    <dt>Current Password:</dt>

            <dd>
                <input type="password" class="input">
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>    <dt>New Password:</dt>

            <dd>
                <input type="password" class="input">
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>    <dt>Verify New Password:</dt>

            <dd>
                <input type="password" class="input">
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>    <dt></dt>

            <dd><small>Passwords must be at least 6 characters long</small>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <dl>    <dt>&nbsp;</dt>

        <dd>
            <button class="button">Login</button>
            <button class="button reset_pass">Reset Password</button>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

And js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

/* SHOW-HIDE LOGIN BOX */

$('.reset_pass').on('click',function(){
    $('#password_fields').show();
    $(this).text('Cansel');
    $(this).addClass('cansel_box');
    $('.cansel_box').on('click',function() {
        $('#password_fields').hide();
        $(this).text('Reset Password');
        $(this).removeClass('cansel_box');
    });
 });
 });
```

Running sample here : http://jsfiddle.net/eKGbL/1/

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Comment: Yes, attaching event handlers inside event handlers, is in most cases fundamentally wrong !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are attaching several click handlers to one element, actually you should delegate the event, but I would suggest `toggle` method:

```
$('.reset_pass').on('click', function () {
    $('#password_fields').toggle();
    $(this).text(function(_, oldText){
        return oldText === 'Reset Password' ? 'Cancel' : 'Reset Password';
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6TwYH/